# AngularJS: Include menu as partial in index.html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

My `index.html` looks basically like this:

```
<body>
  <header ng-controller="navCtrl">
    <!-- quite a bit of html for the menu -->
  </header>
  <div ng-view>
  </div>
</body>
```

Since I cannot use multiple `ng-view`s on one page I was wondering what would be the best way to move the menu (`<header />`) into a partial so my `index.html` stays nice and clean?

Comment: I think `ngInclude` is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use **ng-include** :

```
<header ng-include src="'partials/topbar.htm'">
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make the menu header a directive.  Directives include their own templates so you could encapsulate the functionality and it would be reusable on other pages.

ie something like:  `<header main-nav></header>`  where main-nav is your directive that does whatever it needs to do.

Comment: As I remember, `directives` serves for re-using functionality, but header is complex sub-module of application instead of something that will be re-used.

Comment: Directives can be whstever you want them to be as an encapsulated unit.

Comment: As well as hands! We can run on them too :D (at least it requires acrobatics) http://askinmask.com/2013/08/because-of-what-the-inventor-of-the-sugar-bags/

Comment: Not sure I agree with your analogy but all the same to each their own.  http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2aesyc_dunya-news-japanese-athlete-sets-record-of-running-on-hands-and-feet_news

Comment: As much as I'd like to any directive that outputs simple html would suffice here so it isn't going to add much.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)? It makes what you're saying super simple because you can have multiple ui-views and you can break your navigation into one and the app into another. It's awesome I'd highly recommend.

Answer (score 0):

If your adding a menu that is only used once in a application, don't create a directive. Directives should be used when you want to avoid repeating code. You will probably move on to develop another application and then you will probably need a menu. But nothing can tell you at this point that that application will use the same navigation.
Use the routing in angularjs with ng-view. Add whatever angular you need in the menu part to highlight links in the menu if you need. If the main page gets to big, move the menu area into a ng-include.

Answer (score 0):

Right approach:

- install `ui-router` that will allow you to use multi-views
- `ui-router` separate view placed in top module
- separate controller for `header` module
- separate `templateUrl` for header menu or `templateProvider` to forecast dynamic menus (if you have user role restrictions etc.)

Bad approach:

- `ng-include` with `ng-controller` in it